# Using Safari Web Inspector on Xcode's IOS simulator to view cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, react-native, safari-web-inspector

I am writing a react-native app with with a WebView sign page.  When I inspect the page with the safari web inspector (Develop->Simulator->locahost - signin) I only have three tabs, Resources, Debugger, Console. Under the Resources tab, I can see the page and associated assets e.g. application.js. However, I cannot see the cookies.  A similar thing happens when I on a native page, and viewing JSContext.

How do I view and modify the cookies? My WevView code is

```
<View style={[styles.container]}>
   <WebView
     ref={'webview'}
     automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
     style={styles.webView}
     source={{uri: LOGIN_URL}}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
     startInLoadingState={true}
     scalesPageToFit={true}
   />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) only support Chrome and Firefox, so it appears best to use the web inspectors on these two browsers.

Comment: I have a very regular website, and I don't see the "Storage" tab on mobile either. Did you find any solution?